# Measuring socket buffer in Java IO and NIO

Tags: java, sockets, io, nio

I have coded a simple setup: client connects to server, server starts sending bytes, client reads them, but with a 1 second delay. I have 2 realizations of this: using Java IO and Java NIO. By printing the number of sent bytes by server and the number of received bytes by client I try to measure the size of client buffer in my system. And of course, I double-check it via socket.getReceiveBufferSize() method.

This doesn't have some practical meaning, just an exercise while studing Java IO.

When I run the IO code its ok: socket.getReceiveBufferSize() returns around 8000 bytes and the difference between sent and receved bytes keeps around this number all the time. I.e. I see the following logs: "sent 33000 bytes" and "received 25000 bytes" at the same time in the two consoles.

When I run NIO code the situation is different. The delta is always around 27000 bytes, though the channel.socket().getReceiveBufferSize() returns 8000 as usual.

1. Is my setup correct for my purpose?
2. Why buffer in NIO version looks bigger?
3. Why buffer in NIO version doesn't coinside with getReceiveBufferSize() method result?

Windows, Java 6, client and server located on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. The value returned by getReceiveBufferSize() doesn't vary with transmission. It's the size of the buffer, not the amount of data that's presently in it.
2. NIO doesn't set different socket send/receive buffer sizes from java.net.Socket. Neither of them touch it, unless you do.

Comment: Of course, I understand this, EJP. The problem is that while using NIO I get 8kb by getReceiveBufferSize(), while the difference between sent and received data is 27kb. The question is where do reside that 19kbytes...

Comment: You're overlooking the existence of the socket send buffer at the sender.

Comment: Thanks, EJP, but according to getSendBufferSize() it is also 8192 bytes.